# can not run servlet in cpanel+ tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, cpanel

i use tomcat + cpanel . my jsps and tags correct run but can not run servlet .

my web.xml content is :

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>pack1.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servlet1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

when request www.mydomain.com/Servlet1 get this error (404) :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /Servlet1 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

please help me.

Comment: What context have you deployed your webapplication in?

Comment: the context is <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/healthto/public_html" debug="1"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cpanel suggests that you're using a 3rd party host. A lot of cheapass 3rd party hosts have due to system limitations different rules for deploying servlets. You should be reading their developer guide/documentation/FAQ how exactly to properly deploy servlets on their host. For example, some 3rd party hosts require a specific folder or package structure, or they require a specific URL structure.

Godaddy, for example, requires you to use the URL structure `/servlet/YourServletClassName`, with the `/servlet` prefix path, see also [their FAQ](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/65/adding-a-java-servlet-to-your-web-site).

If you want to have full control over deployment or want to follow standard Java EE rules, you'd rather look for a different  host. For example, [OpenShift](http://openshift.redhat.com/), which is a completely free cloud hosting service using the full fledged JBoss AS 7 application server, including EJB and JPA support and all on em and the free choice between MySQL and PostgreSQL databases.